# Markdown to hide extra information

Tags: support, markdown

Recently I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731422/returning-top-results-for-events-in-a-competition/24524300#24524300) where I included the database schema.

This information I presume is not going to be of use to anyone except the OP, but it takes up most of the room on the page and makes it more difficult to read.

Is there a way to hide this information? The spoiler `>!` just makes it blank, but the area used is the same. Is there a collapse/expand or more/less info toggle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a scroll-bar added to long code-blocks, automatically.
Other than that, there's no functionality available to "Collapse / Expand" blocks of code.

Whatever you do, don't post relevant code off-site. A slightly long answer isn't necessarily bad if it contains useful information that's formatted in a logical way. (Which appears to be the case, in your answer)

Comment: Would this be better as a feature request then?

Comment: Yes, it would be.

Comment: I decided it would be better on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234935/add-expanders-to-markdown-so-users-can-hide-more-info-text